# Import data from excel to sql server C# Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-2008

I'm using sql server 2008. I have a database "CustomerManagement", and a table "Customer" like this:

```
CustomerID    |    Name    |    Money
1             | Paul       | 300
2             | Mary       | 250
3             | David      | 
4             | May        | 
5             | Ann        |
```

And I have an excel file, with some data as the following:

```
CustomerID    |    Money
3             | 100
4             | 150
5             | 175
```

How I can insert "Money" in excel file to sql server based on CustomerID?

I'm using winform C# and MS Excel 2010

Comment: did you search SO or google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750803/import-excel-file-into-microsoft-sql-server-using-c-sharp

Comment: @Asken: yes, i did. But it tutorials insert data from excel to a new table. What I want is insert data to table with specified ID

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve all the data from Excel which you want to insert to sql Database and then loop it and insert to sql server.

[Retrieve Data](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/412468/Excel-csharp-net-retrieving-data-without-opening-e)

[Insert to SQL Database](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/91bd10ce-c83b-4766-920b-2137ddc29908)